# Sphinx - NFS index

Tags: sphinx, nfs

We are running sphinx 1.10 version. We are having multiple sphinx servers under Loadbalancer where searchd is running. We want to share the same index file across multiple servers via NFS. We do not want to do rsync as it would have different servers getting updated with indexes at different time and hence would create inconsistency in the search output.

Due to the .lock file creation, currently via NFS we are unable to start searchd in multiple servers. Any solution would be of great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rsync, and then rotate all the servers in unison. basically you can do the reindexing, syncing. And then control when the servers actully rotate in the new index.

Works well. A couple of mentions of it here

http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/search.html?q=rsync+sighup&f=1

Answer (score 0):

I can say it is impossible to share indexes between two or more searchd instances.
You have to implement something similar to rsync, see how we are doing [Sphinx replication](http://www.ivinco.com/blog/sphinx-replication/).